# Highlight a Post in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, blogs

How can I highlight a post in jekyll like this in facebook?

[image: example of highlighted post on facebook]

The main feature of this function is to keep the post on top.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking for. Do you want to highlight current page entry in your menu ? What do you mean by "keep the post on top" ?

Comment: I was not referring to a page, I meant a publication. I wish one of the publications remain in the top of the page even if the public a new entry. Check my [blog](http://capriatto.github.io)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer you using your blog code as example:

1. Add a tag "featured" to every post you want to be always on top

   ```
   ---
   layout: post
   title:  "Filtrar registros en one2many (on_change)"
   date:   2015-08-07 22:00:00
   categories: Openerp 7
   comments: true
   tag: featured 
   ---
   ```
2. In your index.html

   ```
   <ul>
       {% for post in site.tags.featured %}
           <li><a href="{{ post.url }}" class="featured">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
       {% endfor %}
       {% for post in site.posts limit 5%}
           <li><a href="{{ post.url }}" class="featured">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
       {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   ```

But now there is a problem: the second `for` loop could re-print the same post twice. You can use an `if` tag to print conditionally only *non featured* posts.

To have a cleaner solution, you could tag every post that you want on the index page with a special tag (e.g. home-non-featured) and then loop on this tag. Otherwise you could write a plugin to filter your post using a `is-tagged-with` or `not-tagget-with` syntax.